# Creating a Backbone.js collection coming up with undefined error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, collections

I am on the learning curve here so pardon me if my question seems trivial. I am trying to create a collection in backbone. The problem is when I try to console.log the teamGroup collection, I get an undefined error. Any reason why this is happening?

```
        var team = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                name: "",
                role: "",
                bio: "",
                link: "",
                media: ""
            }
            });

        //Create a collection template that references which model to base it on 
        var teamCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

            model: team

        });

        //Create model instances for each team member
        var teamPayal = new team({
            name: "P Seth",
            role: "Director",
            bio: "Director PS is from Hyberadad.",
            link: "www.filmschool.com",
            media: "www.facebook.com"
        });

        var teamUnio = new team({
            name: "Unio Guiterrez",
            role: "Producer",
            bio: "Unio is a producer from SF",
            link: "www.greengeender.com",
            media: "www.twitter.com/unio"
        });

        var teamScott = new team({
            name: "Scott Baskovich",
            role: "Musician",
            bio: "Scott is a musician from SF",
            link: "www.music.com",
            media: "www.linkedin.com"
        });

        //Create new collection for the team

        var teamGroup = teamCollection([
            teamPayal, teamUnio, teamScott
            ]);

        console.log(teamGroup.toJSON());

    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot `new` before `teamCollection` to create new instance of backbone collection

```
    var teamGroup = new teamCollection([
        teamPayal, teamUnio, teamScott
        ]);
```

There is a convention used by some JavaScript programmers to always start the names of functions constructors with a capital letter (`TeamCollection`) and to always start all instances names with a lowercase letter (`var team = new Team({...})`).